# How to change matplotlib colorbar range on zoom to the limits of the data in the zoomed region

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to automatically change the colorbar limits of a matplotlib tricontourf plot,
when the plot is zoomed, to the maximum and minimum of the shown data. 
I am detecting the zoom with *xlim_changed* signal, but I have no idea how to get the color limits of the zoomed region. 
I tried *get_clim()* on the tricontourf, but that just gives the original limits, not the ones in the zoomed window.
In the end I also want to change the levels, but for the replotting I would also need the new limits.

```
import matplotlib.tri as tri
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def on_xlims_change(event_ax):
    print("updated lims: ", tcf.get_clim())

x = [6,4,8,3]
y = [1,7,3,9]
z = [0,10,4,7] 
triang = tri.Triangulation(x, y)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
tcf = ax.tricontourf(triang, z, levels= 200)
ax.callbacks.connect('xlim_changed', on_xlims_change)
fig.colorbar(tcf)
plt.show()
```

Comment: you will have to get the data from your original data and see what the min/max is in your data.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I should have thought about that.